Bootstrap Accordion not starting with correct icon
I have created a webpage to display the various parts of a privacy policy. I used Bootstrap and its accordion feature to display the information. It runs fine and displays the information along with the standard icons fine.
I want to start it with plus and minus icons to denote the expansion and collapse of the area.
My issue is that on the page's initial load, the accordion starts with minus icons displayed.

If I then expand the item, it correctly shows the collapse (minus) icon

If I collapse it, it will display the correct plus icon.

I have no idea what's going on as I'm not a CSS/HTML person. I have read around, and what's shown in the CSS should work. But it doesn't.
The Icons were converted from SVG using this URL encoder.
The video I used to create my CSS is here.
Here is my CSS that should make the accordion icons change.
.accordion {
    --bs-accordion-btn-bg: #e5e7eb;
    --bs-accordion-active-bg: #e5e7eb;
    --bs-accordion-bg: #e5e7eb;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem; /* Set spacing at bottom of accordian item */

}

.accordion-button {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.accordion-button::after {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3C!--!Font Awesome Pro 6.5.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--%3E%3Cpath d='M256 48a208 208 0 1 1 0 416 208 208 0 1 1 0-416zm0 464A256 256 0 1 0 256 0a256 256 0 1 0 0 512zM232 344c0 13.3 10.7 24 24 24s24-10.7 24-24V280h64c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24s-10.7-24-24-24H280V168c0-13.3-10.7-24-24-24s-24 10.7-24 24v64H168c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24s10.7 24 24 24h64v64z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.accordion-button:not(.collapsed)::after {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3C!--!Font Awesome Pro 6.5.2 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--%3E%3Cpath d='M256 48a208 208 0 1 1 0 416 208 208 0 1 1 0-416zm0 464A256 256 0 1 0 256 0a256 256 0 1 0 0 512zM184 232c-13.3 0-24 10.7-24 24s10.7 24 24 24H328c13.3 0 24-10.7 24-24s-10.7-24-24-24H184z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

I am using fontawesome icons, and these display fine.
here is my head from the page
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=2, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#d3ad56" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Css Files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/reset.css?v=0.2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css?v=0.2">

    <!-- JS Files -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link type="image/png" rel="icon" href="./images/logo.png"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/ZP5T-c_utgZ7_8Ah"/>

    <-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dab436b83c.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

Here is what dev tools shows me

All help is greatly appreciated.
Here is a snippet from the HTML where I define item 10 on the Accordian
<div class="container">
    <div class="accordion" id="privacyAccordion10">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading-10">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse-10" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-10">
                    How long we hold your information
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapse-10" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-10" data-bs-parent="#privacyAccordion10">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <p>We will remove any personal information that will identify you, or we will securely destroy the records when we consider that that personal information is no longer required. This could be a period of seven years after our business relationship with you has ended.</p>
                    <p>However, we may need to maintain certain records for a longer period, for example, where we are required to hold your personal information for regulatory or legal purposes, to provide you with the services you have requested or to maintain adequate business records.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- End of 10th Item -->


What do you see as the applied class/CSS when you inspect using your browser devtools?

Can you show us the relevant HTML? In particular, are you certain that the button has class .collapse set right from the start?

I have updated the main question with the information you requested.

Have you tried including collapsed in the class for the button?

I hadn't but I have tried it now and to still shows the same issue.
I tried it in various combinations of true, false, 0, 1
.accordion-button {
font-size: 2rem;
font-weight: 700;
collapse: true;
}

I think you misunderstood, sorry if I wasn’t clear. collapsed isn’t a CSS property but a class. And note it’s collapsed not collapse. Add it to the buttons class in the HTML so instead of class="accordion-button" put class="accordion-button collapsed "

BOOM! You got iot. I have a different issue now, but the main one is now gone. Now my items with collapsed set are showing as open. Not to worry. Ill fix that. Thanks for your help and putting me straight. HGow do I set your reply as the Answer?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I put the comment into an answer as it solved the problem as set. If you have another question it's best to post it separately.

All sorted. The other issue was with the div after the button element. i had to add the collapse class so finishes as
<div id="collapse-1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-1" data-bs-parent="#privacyAccordion1">


collapsed isn’t a CSS property but a class.
And note it’s collapsed not collapse.
Add it to the buttons class in the HTML so instead of class="accordion-button" put class="accordion-button collapsed"
